# Multi-dimensional array reshaping Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have created a 4-dimensional array (cell) of arrays called "a" where

a{i,j,k,l} = [ v_1 v_2 v_3 v_4] for some vector v. each of the index variables runs from 1 to 10 in steps of 1. I have a total of 10000 entries in the cell.

I want to reshape this cell into another cell whose dimensions are 1x10000.
I want the first element of the new cell to be the first element of a (i.e. a{1,1,1,1}).

I tried using "cat" command but it didn't work. It only produced a single output instead of an array output.

Please help.

Comment: Just use the `reshape` command: `b = reshape(a,1,10000);`

Comment: Thanks Doug, I worked on it yesterday. I figured it out. I was calling b(1), instead i should call b{1,1}. I have 10^8 loops for my DE model. It has been running since last night midnight. I forgot to timeit. I am trying to open another command window while the code is running in one window.

Comment: A slightly more common name for this operation is *flattening* or *vectorisation* of the array.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

```
c=cell(4,4)
for i
for j
for k
for l
c{i,j,k,l} = [v_i v_j v_k v_l];
end
end
end
end

e=reshape(c,1,i*j*k*l);
```

to call the mth element: e{1,m}